# Is it possible that two metric spaces are metrically isomorphic but not homeomorphic.

Tags: metric-spaces

I am trying to find an example of metric spaces $(X,d_x)$ and $(Y,d_y)$ such that they are metrically isomorphic, but not homeomorphic.

I have been attempting to find one, however I have not been able to. This leads me to ask is this possible? I know that there must be an injective isometry from $X$ to $Y$, so there is a continuous function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ where $f$ is an isometry and f(X) = Y. However we also need that $f^{-1}$ is not continuous. Which is making it hard to find such an example.

So the statement is probably false, however I cannot show it. Any hints?

Thanks.

Comment: That's impossible.

Comment: This is not possible.

Comment: Could you explain why not?

Comment: Metric isomorphisms are trivially continuous. ​ ​

Comment: Metrically isomorphic means isometric? So you want an isometry which is not onto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a bijective isometry, $d(f(f^{-1}(x)),(f^{-1}(y)))=d(f^{-1}(x),f^{-1}(y))=d(x,y)$, thus $f^{-1}$ is an isometry and $f^{-1}(B(x,r))=B(f^{-1}(x),r)$ thus $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was after.